# How to get selected rows and column index and count in Word JS

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, word-addins

I have an Word add-in (API 1.3) project where I can insert tables and make them content controls. I use the following code to recognize if the user clicks inside the table or selects any of its cells.

```js
Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged,
  function() {
    Word.run(function(ctx) {
      var ctrl = ctx.document.getSelection().parentContentControl;

      return ctx.sync()
        .then(function() {
          if (!ctrl.isNull) { // found - clicked inside the control
            // ... load some properties, ...
            ctrl.load('tag'); // How to get startRow, startCol, rowCount, colCount?

            ctx.sync()
              .then(function() {
                console.log(ctrl.tag);
              }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
              });
          }
        }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
  });
```

Is there a way to get the startRow, startCol, rowCount, colCount from here as in the binding event handlers for selectionChanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sharing this question.  2 issues with your code:

1. You are subscribing to the document selection change, but you really want to do a Binding Selection Change. Note that coordinates are only returned on Table Bindings.
2. Once you have a table binding and subscribing to the right type of event, you need to add the event args on the handler to get access to the values you need.

Check out the following code to see how to create a table binding and also how to use  the eventArgs on the handler to get the information you need (also note that you will get undefined on the rows acting as headers, if you have headers defined in the table):

```js
 Office.context.document.bindings.addFromSelectionAsync(Office.BindingType.Table, function (result) {
            if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                // after creating the binding i am adding the handler for the BindingSelectionChanged, check out eventArgs usage....
                var binding = result.value;
                binding.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.BindingSelectionChanged, function (eventArgs) {
                    app.showNotification('Selection Coordinates: ' + eventArgs.startColumn + " " + eventArgs.columnCount + " " + eventArgs.startRow + " " + eventArgs.rowCount);
                });
            }
        });
```

Hope this puts you in the right direction. thanks!
Juan.

Comment: I use content controls for the tables and I don't have bindings for them. Does it mean that if a user clicks inside a table, I need to find the content control that is attached to the table, select the whole table, make a binding from it, then ask the user to select the cells again so I can get the columns and rows? Having the binding and the content control on the table at the same time sounds like an overkill.

Comment: if you want to get events, you need to create a binding, and in Word that means creating a content control. Note that the binding is something you need to do only once, on this case seems to be at the time you actually insert the table in the document. After you create the binding and the event handlers the event will just trigger, you dont need to tell the user to re-select the cells.

Comment: I add the table with `var table = ctx.document.body.insertTable(value.length, value[0].length, "end", value); var myContentControl = table.insertContentControl(); ctx.sync()`. Then look for bindings in the document with `doc.bindings.getAllAsync` and I have none. Do I need to use `doc.bindings.addFromSelectionAsync` at moment of creation of content control so your suggested way to work?

Comment: what i recommend you to do in this case is to add a title to the content control, so after you do the var myContentControl = table.insertContentControl();   do a myContentControl.title="Foo"; and then you can actually use the doc.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync("foo","table"...) that way you can create a binding more reliably.  please check the documentation here https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/bindings.addfromnameditemasync

Comment: Thank you, Juan! I will customize your suggestion a bit and implement that.

Comment: I still have an issue. From the event arguments of bindingSelectionChanged I cannot get if the user selected the header row or not. If rowCount is undefined, user selected only the header. If rowCount is a number, she selected some rows in the body. But in the latter case, I do not know if the selection includes cells in the header. Any ideas?

Comment: If startRow is undefined it means header(s) is selected

Comment: Not really. The same result comes out regardless if I select header and 1st row of body or 1st row only: rowCount = 1, startRow = 1 https://db.tt/nzN1Lr66

Comment: I solved my problem in a different way. Adding a header-less table within a binding, then adding the content control over that. It works perfect. Thanks for the support!